# how to run single test case from jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have 10 test cases in testng suite,i need to execute single or individual test cases from jenkinks,can any one help me out how to execute single test case from jenkins,i tried maven surfire commands mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test include test command into golas and executed but its not working,please refer data and correct me how to set goals in jenkins for execute single test case.
"mvn clean compile install  -DPICK_CONFIGURATION_FROM="JENKINS" -DEXECUTION_MODE="Remote" -**Dtest=TestCircle#EAConsoleLandingPageTest test** -DPLATFORM="WEB"  -DOPERATING_SYSTEM="WINDOWS" -DBROWSER="chrome" -DCOMPUTERNAME="Test" -DTEST_ENVIRONMENT="RUNFC" -DPLAN_ID="" -DTEST_TYPE="Smoke" -DGRID_URL="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub""

Below is the sample test suite:
classes>

```
        <class
            name="com.ea.automation.tests.EAConsoleLandingPageTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="clickOnGetStartedBtn" />
                <include name="selectProjectFromLandingPage" />
                <include name="clickOnEAConsoleIcon" />
                <include name="verifyRequestProjectAccess" />
                <include name="verifyProjectAccess" />
                <include name="verifyHomePageRedierecting" />
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class
            name="com.ea.automation.tests.EAConsoleSelfServiceTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="clickOnCreateNewproject" />
                <include name="verifyProjectUserAcess" />
                <include name="switchProjects" />
                <include name="clickOnProjectSettings" />
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class
            name="com.ea.automation.tests.EAConsoleNotificationAppTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="selectProject" />
                <include name="clickOnNotification" />
                <include name="checkAllWdgetNotifications" />
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class
            name="com.ea.automation.tests.EAConsoleSupportAppTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="clickOnSupportApp" />
                <include name="checkCreateTicket" />
                <include name="clickOnCloseErrorMessageModel" />
                <include name="clickOnSupportFromApp" />
                <include name="clickOnSupportEmail" />
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class
            name="com.ea.automation.tests.EAConsoleSDKDownloadsAppTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="selectProject" />
                <include name="clickOnSDKDownloads" />
            </methods>
        </class>
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I am suggesting is not preferable. Because the sole purpose of running Jenkins is to run a suite of test cases and not individual ones. But you could implement your idea in the following way.

1. Add three string parameters to the Jenkins job. One parameter points to the testng xml file name, second parameter points to the class name, and the third parameter points to the test name.
2. Create and have another testng.xml file in your project repo. Rename this file as small.xml
3. So the first Build parameter should be small.xml
4. Jenkins has the capability to execute shell script before the maven build starts.
5. So we are going to fetch the arguments that we used as Jenkins Build parameters inside the shell script to modify the small.xml file and modify the pom.xml file to point to the small.xml.
6. **sed** command in a shell script will help to replace the existing text in pom.xml and small.xml file. You could search this on the internet.

I had implemented this approach in one of the projects that I worked on for picking different suite files based on the Jenkins build parameters. This approach works. So during runtime, based on the Jenkins Build Parameters you pass, the corresponding tests will be run by Jenkins.